# Is an 800Va/400w AVR+surge protector enough for my PC with a 550 W Power supply?

Tags: power-supply, desktop-computer, compatibility

Is an 800Va/400w AVR+surge protector enough for my PC with a 550 W Power supply?

Computer specs:
CPU: Ryzen 5 2600.
MBD: B450 Tomahawk MAX.
GPU: Radeon RX 5500xt.
RAM: 2x8 3200mhz.
SSD: 250 GB.
Fans: x8 120mm w/ RGB.

Comment: I would vote to close and migrate to one of the electrical sites. But the option is not there, so voting to leave open.

Answer (score 1):

As @K7AAY pointed out - no.

Unfortunately the figure in Watts is the important one. From a practical POV on a consumer UPS, a VA rating is a marketing scam for bigger numbers.

I do note that although we are saying "no" it is technically possible it will work in your case - as a 550 watt power supply will likely not be drawing 550 watts most of the time. The problem is that it *could* draw more and this *could* cause a shutdown or damage to the UPS - small ups's are often not well made.

Another couple of things - as a rule, the smaller the ups the smaller the battery and the more stress draining it a full rate causes. Likewise larger ups's have parts able to tolerate more power draw so they last longer.

Comment: I am using a 255W UPS from APC with a 1300W PSU in my desktop; It has saved me from losing work due to brief power flickers, but I would still shut down my PC if the power completely went out. It may even be a fire hazard to use an under-rated UPS like that for longer than a minute.

Comment: It’s not a fire hazard. The have all kinds of protection built-in. They will shut down if more power is drawn than they can provide.

Comment: @DanielB I don't think you can generalize like that. Certainly its going to stress the batteries, caps, transistors, and these cheap UPS's are not built to last. Putting a 1300 watt PC on a 255w ups is foolhardy.

Comment: Looking at the PSU rating doesn’t help either. // I believe a modern quality UPS will not catch fire if you draw more power. It will shut down though.

Comment: @Romen You live a charmed life.

Answer (score 1):

I'm definitely of the opinion that, "when you are shopping for a UPS box, *splurge."*

Buy a well-made unit whose rated capacity clearly exceeds that of your computer.  (Many of the devices you find at an office supply store are *not* "well-made!"  Shop online.)

The UPS will act to stabilize the power that is reaching your computer.  If a brief fluctuation or outage occurs, the UPS will catch it.  If power fails for an extended time, it gives you time to shut down your computer normally.

Every now and then, reach over to the plug and yank it out of the wall.  Did the UPS actually do its job?  Never assume that it will.

Answer (score 0):

Is 400W capacity of a surge protector equal to or greater than the 550W power supply?

No?

Then it's not enough.

Comment: Why would you compare the maximum output power of the power supply to the maximum output power of the surge protector? The output of the surge protector is connected to the input of the power supply and his computer probably won't get anywhere close to the limit of his power supply either. So your conclusion is just an assumption.

Comment: PCs, as with other electronica, when powered up often draw much, much more than steady state. I test this frequently with watt meters on my bench at {Large Multinational Semiconductor Manufacturer Corp.}. Also observed by measurement on my 1500W power amp in my ham shack at home. No brag, jes' fact.

Comment: Precisely. So why did you compare the steady state maximum output of the surge protector to the steady state maximum output of the power supply? Your answer is just wrong. That isn't correct for the steady state (because there's no reason to think the power supply will provide its maximum output and it's the input to the power supply you'd need to compare) and it isn't correct for peak (because you used the steady state maximums for both devices). So ... ?!

Answer (score 0):

I would look into how to read surge protector values. I was looking for the [clamping rating](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Surge_protector#Clamping_voltage), but I don't think you supplied it.

This is the value that the protector will leak through during a surge. You want a device that was rated by Underwriters Laboratory (UL 1449, v3), because this rating part of their battery. Here the lower the value the better.

For a home PC, I think that's enough to know. But you should consider surge protectors like motorcycle helmets, let them save you once and then throw them away, because they've already absorbed the damage. This isn't true for all surge protectors, but I suggest reading the linked article while considering what type of structure you're in (is it a home vulnerable to lightning strikes, or do you only have to worry about your apartment building's maximum surge?).